# How do I return the actual data from an Axios async call?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios

I have the following code in a `react-redux` powered application. The code is split across a couple of files but I've just combined it below for simplicity:

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

const authClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://api.empaygo.local",
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    }
});

const getUser = async (userId) => {
    const result = await authClient.get(`/users/${userId}`);
    return result;
}


const user = users.getUser(1);
console.log(user);
```

The final console log is always:

[image: Promise result]

And I cannot work out how to get the data that I need out of it. Any help would great :)

Comment: also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: @Quentin This did help, thank you. I understand that I should probably use a callback, but I need to stop my component from rendering (or show that it is loading) before I get the response back. I could have just spent too long looking at this to work it out but are you able to help at all?

Comment: You can't do that. Have the async function store a value in the state which will trigger a rerender.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const user = users.getUser(1);
// inside this cb you will get actual object
user.then((data) => console.log(data))
```

or just

```
 users.getUser(1).then((data) => {
   // you can set this data into state or return another Promise
   console.log(data)
 })
```

You have to work with [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: But I'm trying to assign the response data to a variable to use throughout the component, not just console log it

Comment: Inside callback function, you can do whatever you want. Assign to a variable if needed or save is state .....